# Reflection in C# to modify a private constant field in a class

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following class:

```
class RuleParser
{
   private const String FILE = "./rules/DetectionStrategies.xml";
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Now in my test project I want to set the FILE constant to another value. How can I achieve that using Reflection?

Comment: Why aren't you using the config file to store this kind of values?

Comment: What do you mean with don't know the config file? Each .net project has a config file. It is either a web.config or app.config depending on project type.

Comment: I didn't know that there is something like a config file

Comment: Trying to change a constant is not reasonable. Constants are constants.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You fell into a trap...

```
const != readonly
```

If it was read-only, you could do that, but `const` means *compile-time* constant, which compilers in turn embed into the resulting program. Hence what you do won't have an effect on pretty much any program, yours or others'.

Comment: Technically speaking, it's still possible to change it. Even though it's set by the compiler, you can locate the variable in the binary file and change it there.

Comment: Yes... hence why I said "what you do won't have an effect on pretty much any program", not "this is impossible." Technically speaking, it *would* have an effect on a program if that program was compiled with a rather dumb compiler that didn't inline the value of the field... hence the "pretty much". :)

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your config file:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DetectionStrategies" value="./rules/DetectionStrategies.xml" />
</appSettings>
```

But I would have it as a property with a private setter instead like such:

```
class RuleParser
{
    private string _file = string.Empty;
    private string File 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_file))
                _file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DetectionStrategies"];
            return _file;
        }
        private set;
    }
}
```

You need to remember to include the `System.Configuration`.

**EDIT:** Since it has to be a compile time constant when you're assigning values to a `const` I removed that and only kept the "property" with private set solution.

**EDIT 2:** The important part of this is that you should only use `const` for true constants, configurable values should be configurable and a good place for that is the config file. Although, you don't have to use the config file, you could as well write your own configuration class that goes against a database instead or against a database with the configuration file as fallback. I might be thinking that you want to use a `static` variable and not `const` but that depends on how you're using the variable and in what context.

Comment: Ehm, the nature of const is that it is 100% const. You can't assign it a value from anything else than a C# constant.

Comment: @Dykam: I thought that was the case but not 100 %... I added a sentence about it.

Comment: That's true, but I think his main problem is that he is not using the config file for parameters that should be configurable. If he decide to use a `readonly` or property doesn't matter to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change a `const` in runtime, (or a `readonly` or whatever), I'd suggest you consider to make some design changes to improve the testability of your code.

Some simple examples would be:

1. Move the value to `App.Config` so that the test can have different values.
2. Abstract the file path from the `RuleParser` class by providing it in the constructor. Either by specifying the path itself, or by providing some interface (e.g. `IFileParserConfig`) that would provide the value in runtime.